# C# string to list

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I am *really* new to C# and am trying to troubleshoot a test of some code that uses Amazon SES to send email.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void SendEmailTest()
    {
        SESEmailProvider target = new SESEmailProvider();

        string ToEmailAddresses = "someone@gmail.com";
        string FromEmailAddress = "no-reply@mydomain.com";
        string Subject = "Test";
        string EmailBody = "Hello world.";
        string expected = string.Empty;
        string actual;
        actual = target.SendEmail(ToEmailAddresses, FromEmailAddress, Subject, EmailBody);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

The error message in Visual Studio is:

```
string SESEmailProvider.SendEmail(
 System.Collections.Generic.List<string> ToEmailAddresses,
 string FromEmailAddress, string Subject, string EmailBody)

Error:

 The best overloaded method match for 'MyServices.SESEmailProvider.SendEmail(
   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>, string, string, string)'
  has some invalid arguements.
```

I think the issue is that it's expecting ToEmailAddresses to be a list, not a single string, but I'm struggling to find a way to convert/handle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well you've defined the variable ToEmailAddresses as a string, but you want it to be a list.

there are many ways to define and fill a list, but the most compact is:

```
var toEmailAddresses = new List<string> { "someone@gmail.com" }
```

the above creates a new list, and initializes it with a single string "someone@gmail.com"

Comment: note that you can initialize the list with multiple values by comma separating them  e.g. .....{ "item1", "item2", "item3" }

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly. I'll accept the answer as soon as the wait time is up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

SendMail expects a List as it's first argument - not a string.

So, do:

```
List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
toAddresses.Add("someone@mail.com");
```

pass toAddresses as the first arg

The clue was in the error message.  It expects List, string, string, string

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'MyServices.SESEmailProvider.SendEmail(
>   System.Collections.Generic.List, string, string, string)'
>   has some invalid arguements.

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestMethod()] 
public void SendEmailTest() 
{ 
    SESEmailProvider target = new SESEmailProvider(); 

    List<string> ToEmailAddresses = new List<string>() {"someone@gmail.com"}; 
    string FromEmailAddress = "no-reply@mydomain.com"; 
    string Subject = "Test"; 
    string EmailBody = "Hello world."; 
    string expected = string.Empty; 
    string actual; 
    actual = target.SendEmail(ToEmailAddresses, FromEmailAddress, Subject, EmailBody); 
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method."); 
}
```

Try that.  I have changed your variable from a `string` to a `List<string>`.